# Как авторизоваться в BTC кошельке?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, blockchain

есть существующий аккаунт на https://www.blockchain.com/ (авторизация по GUID + PWD)

Каким образом я могу авторизоваться в этом BTC кошельке чтобы (получать баланс / отправлять BTC)

Смотрел в сторону библиотек на C# / Node - Но все они создают новый кошелек и я не понимаю каким образом я могу авторизоваться в уже существующий...

Возможно мне нужно через chrome dev в авторизованном кошельке каким-то образом получить какие-то ключи доступа или что-то в этом роде..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blockchain MyWallet Module](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-node/tree/master/MyWallet)

```
var MyWallet = require('blockchain.info/MyWallet')

var options = { apiCode: 'myAPICode', apiHost: 'http://localhost:3000' }
var wallet = new MyWallet('myIdentifier', 'myPassword123', options)
wallet.getBalance().then(function (response) {
    console.log('My balance is %d!', response.balance);
})
```